# A la hora de usar una imagen no me quiere funcionar y me sale un icono en lugar de la imagen

Tags: html, angular

tengo unas imágenes en una carpeta llamada "imagenes" pero a la hora de llamar la imagen y cargar la pagina no se me visualiza y en su lugar se ve un icono.

[image: Error presentado]
[image: Ruta imagen]

E cambiado muchas veces la ruta y en ninguna me a funcionado, e probado con imágenes externas del navegador y si se me visualizan, pero cuando voy a tomar una imagen propia se me visualiza el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes de colocarlo asi

`<img src="../../../imagenes/logoTraspa.jpg"/>`

ya que en codigo debes seguir la ruta exacta de la imagen.

lo ideal es dentro de "src" crear una carpeta "assets" y dentro colocar todos los recursos a usar

Comment: Muchas gracias, con la ruta de assets si me funciono!

Comment: @DavidCortes recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta si resolvió tu duda, haciendo clic en el _tick_ bajo los votos de la respuesta (a la izquierda)